# fscanf - I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Tags: c, scanf

```
 char id;
 int num, r;
 if (argc != 2) {
   printf("error\n");
   exit(1);
 }

 FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
 if (file == NULL) {
   printf("error\n");
   exit(1);
  }

  while ((r = fscanf(file, "%c\t%d", &id, &num)) != EOF) {
    if(r == 2) {
      printf("id: %c, value: %d\n", id, num);
    }
    else if (r!=2) {
      printf("bad input\n");
    }
  }
```

The file I'm trying to read looks like:

> i 10
>
> i 12
>
> d 10
>
> d 12

(The character/integer are tab separated). My output is:

> id: i, value: 10
>
> bad input
>
> id: i, value: 12
>
> bad input
>
> id: d, value: 10
>
> bad input
>
> id: d, value: 12
>
> bad input

WHAT am I doing wrong? "Bad input" should ONLY be printed if the file is incorrectly formatted. The file above demonstrates a properly formatted file. I don't understand how `r == 2` and `r != 2` at the same time (both conditions are somehow met).

Comment: Don't check for scanf to return EOF. You should be checking whether it returns the number of expected items or not.

Comment: '\n' and spaces have significance too.

Comment: You shouldn't `exit` if you've got a `FILE` opened: it won't get cleanly closed.

Comment: From your question, this seems to be a runtime problem.  However, the posted code does not compile.   Certainly you do not expect us to guess as to which headers, etc are in your actual code.

Comment: this line: `printf("error\n");` tells the user nothing.  After checking the number of command line parameters.  When the command line contains the wrong number of parameters, the useful output is a 'usage' statement,  similar to: `printf( "USAGE: %s <parm1Info> <parm2info>", argv[0]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
while((r = fscanf(file, " %c\t%d", &id, &num)) != EOF)  //Whitespace before %c
```

Might solve your problem. Because when you use

```
fscanf(file, "%c\t%d", &id, &num)
```

Then it leaves a newline character which is consumed in the next iteration.
As your next iteration your `id` get `\n` and `num` gets the character.

But when you put extra white space before `%c` which tells `fscanf()` to ignore whitespaces(including Tab, space or newline).
Thus your `fscanf()` gets two parameter(character and number).

Comment: Looks like it worked! Can you please explain why the whitespace made the difference? Thank you so much!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Please change

```
while ((r = fscanf(file, "%c\t%d", &id, &num)) != EOF) {
```

to

```
 while ((r = fscanf(file, "%c\t%d\n", &id, &num)) != EOF) {
```

Adding \n at the end in fscanf.

In your file, lines are terminated with \n.
In next read it does not go well.